# Caps and Shift key using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem. I have to identify my Caps Lock is on or not?

If my caps lock on then i have to tell user that your caps on. but the problem is if some one press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then it should behave normally.i think key events of  <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on + <kbd>a</kbd> equal to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.

How can i identify only my Caps Lock key on. i have seen some example in stackoevrflow but these are not working fine.

This all should be using javascript or jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect caps lock on/off using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery)

Comment: Like you said, I don't know if you can detect it. Most programs seem to just go with a generic warning of "make sure your caps lock is off" and that it's case sensitive. Of course, you could detect several capitals in a row and then "suspect" that caps lock is on...

Comment: you have to check for the shift on every key up.

Comment: @Matt- in javascript/jquery Caps Lock on + a and Shift + a returning same sky code. so i can not differentiate them using current code provided in current answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)" />

function handleKeyPress(e){

    var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    if(key >= 65 && key <=90 && !e.shiftKey){

        alert("CAPS LOCK ON");

    }

}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/pNc35/2/

Answer (score 0):

try the following

http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2008/jul/2/javascript-detecting-caps-lock/

Comment: sorry friend, this code is not working for me.when your caps lock on it will return e.shiftKey= true, it fails for me

Comment: have a look at the article this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery there's a second solution in there. also this problem has no definite solution as browsers suck. (so it may never work correctly in some browsers)