# show caps lock is on using jQuery

Tags: jquery

When i open login page if the caps lock is on i need to show immediately caps lock is on.
    I saw some posts  like

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery) Which is showing in keypress.But i want to show immediately after page loaded.
     How i can do this using jQuery .Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript dupliacte of this ..

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/896515/779158 . I think its in jquery as well.

Comment: the link provided by me and this is same.I need different solution

Comment: You **have** to wait for a key to be pressed before detecting. There's no way to see if caps lock is on naturally

Comment: i saw in some site which is displaying whenever i open login form

Comment: i did not remember exactly where it is

Comment: @PSR I'm guessing it used a Java Applet or Flash.

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, why do you need this functionality?

Comment: I think this is not possible yet, as most web browsers currently do not provide the status of caps lock, scroll lock, num lock. Even if newer version of web browsers do provide the status, older web browsers will still remained the same. It's like asking lynx 1.0 to fetch data through AJAX.

Comment: to show some note to the user

Comment: does it need to be very responsive OR can there be a bit of lagg?

Comment: @1337holiday what it mean.I am poor in english.please explain in simple words

Comment: What you can do is use a cookie/localstorage to store the state of the CAPS button. If a user pressed it right before they reloaded the page, it will be toggeled `on` and you can display your note and clear the caps state back to `"unpressed"` once the page loads

Comment: before giving a down vote please explain why you are voting a down vote

Comment: I didnt downvote...you may want to reconsider your selected answer below.

Comment: @1337holiday  i meant someone downvoted.not yiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but you cannot get the state of a keyboard button on page load. You have to analyze a keyCode of a keypress. That is the only way.

Check this post: [detect caps lock status on page load (or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371732/detect-caps-lock-status-on-page-load-or-similar)

Answer (score 1):

There is a jQuery plugin called capslockstate that will monitor the state of the caps lock key over the entire page, not just in specific fields.

You can either query the state of the caps lock key or define event listeners to react to state changes.

The plugin does a better job of detection and state management than the other suggestions here, including working with non-English keyboards, monitoring the use of the Caps Lock key itself, and not forgetting the state if non alpha characters are typed.

There are two demos, [one showing basic event binding](http://jsfiddle.net/nosilleg/zVCU5/) and another [showing the warning only when the password field has focus](http://jsfiddle.net/nosilleg/tBB58/).

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* 
* Bind to capslockstate events and update display based on state 
*/
$(window).bind("capsOn", function(event) {
    $("#statetext").html("on");
});
$(window).bind("capsOff", function(event) {
    $("#statetext").html("off");
});
$(window).bind("capsUnknown", function(event) {
    $("#statetext").html("unknown");
});

/*
* Additional event notifying there has been a change, but not the state
*/
$(window).bind("capsChanged", function(event) {
    $("#changetext").html("changed").show().fadeOut();
});

/* 
* Initialize the capslockstate plugin.
* Monitoring is happening at the window level.
*/
$(window).capslockstate();

// Call the "state" method to retreive the state at page load
var initialState = $(window).capslockstate("state");
$("#statetext").html(initialState);});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* 
* Bind to capslockstate events and update display based on state 
*/
$(window).bind("capsOn", function(event) {
    if ($("#Passwd:focus").length > 0) {
        $("#capsWarning").show();
    }
});
$(window).bind("capsOff capsUnknown", function(event) {
    $("#capsWarning").hide();
});
$("#Passwd").bind("focusout", function(event) {
    $("#capsWarning").hide();
});
$("#Passwd").bind("focusin", function(event) {
    if ($(window).capslockstate("state") === true) {
        $("#capsWarning").show();
    }
});

/* 
* Initialize the capslockstate plugin.
* Monitoring is happening at the window level.
*/
$(window).capslockstate();});
```

[The code for the plugin](https://github.com/nosilleg/capslockstate-jquery-plugin/blob/master/src/jquery.capslockstate.js) is viewable on GitHub.

Comment: Its working when capslock key pressed only. But if we used *shift* key means its not coming.