# Detect caps lock on/off on a Html.TextBoxFor and Html.PasswordFor using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I found this: [Detect caps lock on/off using jQuery [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery)

It works when I use it with `<input>` tags. But it doesn't work when I use it with  `Html.TextBoxFor` or `Html.PasswordFor` .

Is it possible to detect the state of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key on a `Html.TextBoxFor` and `Html.PasswordFor` using jQuery?

Comment: what is Html.TextBoxFor - an element with ".textBoxFor" class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect caps lock on/off using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery)

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky I assume he is reffering to asp.net-mvc

Comment: May be helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348792/how-do-you-tell-if-caps-lock-is-on-using-javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect caps lock on/off using jQuery \[duplicate\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308895/detect-caps-lock-on-off-using-jquery)